# how do i copy an array correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables

im trying to make a copy of an array but when i change the copy it also changes the original.
i have tried using `Object.assign([], scenes)`, `scenes.clone()` and tried using a for loop

```
if(localStorage.getItem(saveName) == null){
    var nonLoopScenes = [...scenes];
    nonLoopScenes.forEach(element=>{
        element.objects.forEach(element2=>{
            element2.scene = null;
        });
    });
    console.log(nonLoopScenes);
    console.log(scenes);
    localStorage.setItem(saveName,JSON.stringify(scenes));
}
```

Comment: can you please add the result of the console.log()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: scenes and nonLoopScenes are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try `const arrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialArray))`, although the method using the spread operator should work as well.

Comment: i can't do that because the scenes array has a reference to it self multiple places.
exaple:`
var a = {name:"Oliver"};
var b = {name:"Noah", friend:a};
a.friend = b;
`